# Python Error: TypeError: 'module' object is not callable

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have written the simplest python code (module) :

```
def newplus(x, y):
    return x*y
```

This is stored in a folder sabya (which is my package). The folder has `_init_` and `newplus.py` files.

In my IDLE I can open the module `sabya.newplus`. When I give `import sabya.newplus` there is no error. but when I issue :

```
>>> sabya.newplus(2, 3)
```

I am getting this error

```
   Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#15>", line 1, in <module>
    sabya.newplus(2, 3)
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

Comment: Note that `'_init_' != '__init__'`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You need to qualify the function as follow:

```
sabya.newplus.newplus(2, 3)
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. It worked. I am new to Python. Today is the first I am learning Python so didn't it at all. I think the way it works is sabya is the package(directory), newplus is the module(.py file) and within it newplus is the function. so my function has to be qualified as package.module.function_name. Am I right?

Comment: Another way of importing: `from sayba.newplus import newplus`and then call `newplus(2, 3)`.

Comment: Thanks a lot again. I added another function hello(str) to the newplus.py file and called sabya.newplus.hello('test). It worked. Thanks for helping me understand the concept.